# Is git-lfs needed to push and pull a repo?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

Does a repo with [`git lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) integration needed `git lfs` installed to push **and** pull from a repository?

Is it possible to have `git lfs` installed on only the machine that is **pushing** the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using git-lfs to interact with repositories with lfs-stored large files is only necessary if you need to read/write those large files. Without git-lfs installed, the large files will be checked out as text files with the LFS metadata; as long as you don't need/touch those files, everything should continue to work for those that do have git-lfs.